# How to do click on coordinates with appium (C#)

Tags: c#, android, appium

I use Appium + C# to make some test on Android
In older version of Appium for clicking on coordinates i use command `driver.Tap(1, x, y, 1);`

But i download new version of Appium and this command not works

And now for clicking on coordinates must use TouchAction (i use code from internet, but this code not works)

May anybody give me example for clicking on coordinates which works?

[image: this code not works]

[image: vesion of Appium]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 1):

I feel Appium Studio would be better than Appium Desktop in your case. They provide support for the Appium versions without changing their built-in commands.
And the commands are very simple to try. You can migrate your code to Appium Studio with minimal efforts.
For clicking at specific co-ordinates, its just

```
client.ClickCoordinate(100, 100, 1);
```

Check out [this](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/TDT/SeeTestAutomation+-+ClickCoordinate) documentation for more details on click command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **io.appium.java_client.TouchAction**.

```
new TouchAction(driver)
            .press(PointOption.point(100,100))
            .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(ofSeconds(1)))
            .release().perform();
```

> Above code is for java. hope you can convert it into c# code.